# Função não está sendo executada no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Javascript**

```
function user(){
   input = document.getElementById("user").value;
   label = document.getElementById("tuser");
   if(label.style.display == "block"){
      if(input.length >= 1){
         label.innerHTML = "Usuário deve conter mais 5 caracteres.";
         if(input.length >= 5){
            label.style = "display:none";
         }
      }
   }
}

function pass(){
   input = document.getElementById("pass").value;
   label = document.getElementById("tpass");
   if(label.style.display == "block"){
      if(input.length >= 1){
         label.style = "display:none";
      }
   }
}
```

Ambas, não estão sendo executadas, portanto retorna um erro no Console do Chrome

```
(index):225 Uncaught TypeError: pass is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeypress ((index):225)
```

**HTML (chama função)**

```
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="user" onkeypress="user()" autofocus maxlength="12" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu Usuário">
<input type="password" name="senha" id="pass" onkeypress="pass()" maxlength="16" class="form-control" placeholder="Sua Senha">
```

Função irá fazer alteração em

```
<font color="#ff0000" id="tuser" class="animation-slideUp inserted" style="display:none;">Insira seu usuário.</font>
<font color="#ff0000" id="tpass" class="animation-slideUp inserted" style="display:none;">Insira sua senha.</font>
```

> Achei muito estranho isso ter acontecido, pois os códigos estão
>   "corretos" (eu acho). Executei-os no console e não surgiu nenhum erro.

Comment: Essas funções JS foram definidas no próprio arquivo HTML ou em um arquivo JS separado? Se é separado, como incluiu o arquivo JS no arquivo HTML?

Comment: Foi definido no próprio arquivo HTML.

Comment: Pode colocar o código completo? Aliás, evite utilizar o elemento `font`. Ele já está obsoleto desde o HTML 4.

Comment: Progrando, fora o código, nos diga o que você quer com esse código, talvez possamos te ajudar na lógica, pois eu percebi que tem bastante coisa desnecessária. ;)

Comment: Seu problema é algum erro em uma linha antes dessas funções. Assim o script não as carregou na memória e na prática elas se tornaram inexistentes. Por isso é bom postar o código completo para analisarmos.

Comment: Após o envio do formulário o javascript verifica se os campos foram preenchidos, se o campo não for preenchido vai aparecer uma mensagem de erro abaixo do input (no caso o label). Então se digitar no input a mensagem vai sumir, e no usuário após o primeiro digito vai aparecer um erro que precisa ter mais de 5 caracteres, dai digita as 5 e o erro some.

Comment: function validate(){
     
  var valid = true;
  
         if (document.formlog.usuario.value == ""){
   document.getElementById('tuser').style = "display:block;";
              valid = false;
         }
         
         if(document.formlog.senha.value == ""){
   document.getElementById('tpass').style = "display:block;";
            valid = false;
         }
   
   if(valid == true){
    loader();
   }
   
         return valid;
   
}

Answer (score -1):

A ordem com que é feita a referência do script JS no HTML importa.

Insere um console.log antes das funcões e vê-se na linha de comandos do browser  (F12 em princípio/ inspect element > Console) aparece. Se aparece é porque está a chamar o ficheiro, se não aparece, verifica os caminhos.

"onkeypress" só faz sentido se tiveres um script com o loading feito, tens de abrir uma função gigante no script com "document.onLoad" ou "onready" e metes a chamar as funções lá para dentro. O browser ao correr o DOM, vai fazer loading dos scripts JS primeiro antes de qualquer carregamento *concreto* (aka, HTML e CSS) da tua página e se isso acontecer tu não vais conseguir chamar nenhuma função daí.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     //funcoes ca para dentro a serem chamadas
    console.log( "ready!" ); //se este console já der, é porque te faltava isto do document
})
```

este código é em JQuery, por isso convém teres uma biblioteca JQuery a ser chamada antes de qualquer outro script teu JS

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
    **COLOCAREI AS FUNÇÕES AQUI? EX:** function user() { }
})

Comment: Sim, mas experimenta primeiro o console.log e vê se aparece na consola do browser. Se aparecer, então poderás trabalhar o teu script apartir daí. 

No entanto, para fazeres o que queres, aconselho-te a usares frameworks. Existem imensas frameworks de Front-end que te ajudam a fazer essas coisas e com exemplos concretos.

Comment: Não adiantou nada.

Comment: Mas não apareceu nenhum console.log na consola do browser?